# Remove bold formatting from chars in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, formatting, format

I use the following code in order to remove formatting. Somehow it does not work.

```
Sub rep_test()
Dim TempS As String

TempS = Replace_chars("]", "]")
End Sub

Function Replace_chars(search_txt As String, replace_txt As String)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
       
        .Text = search_txt
        .Replacement.Text = replace_txt
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Format:=False

End Function
```

TextSample:
Aaa [BBB] **CC [DDD]**

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove formatting the correct way to do it is to apply the character style "Default Paragraph Font". This will reset the formatting to match the underlying paragraph style. It also has the advantage that you don't need to know what formatting needs to be removed/applied.

```
Sub FindAndResetFormatting(search_txt As String)
   With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Text = search_txt
      .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleDefaultParagraphFont)
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .Format = True
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That will do a whole lot more than remove bold formatting for a particular character - which is all the OP's thread title and code suggests he's trying to achieve.

Comment: @macropod - I was responding to the text of the question. *<<I use the following code in order to remove formatting>>*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Sub rep_test()
Call Replace_chars("]")
End Sub

Sub Replace_chars(search_txt As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = search_txt
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = False
    .Format = True
    .Forward = True
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: not working...no changes in the text made

Comment: Works for me... Perhaps you haven't specified the text to be changed and/or your requirements correctly.